# SQL use COUNT (and GROUP BY?) to perform calculation in a SELECT without excluding records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I have a test database, set up with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE summary (
   row_sid SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   product_list_sid INT,
   amount INT,
   qty INT
);

CREATE TABLE list_header (
   product_list_sid INT
);

CREATE TABLE list_detail (
   product_list_sid INT,
   product_sid INT
);

CREATE TABLE product (
   product_sid SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   product_description VARCHAR(60)
);

INSERT INTO product(product_description) VALUES ("can"), ("bottle");

INSERT INTO list_detail VALUES (1,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2),(2,2),(2,1);

INSERT INTO list_header VALUES (1), (2);

INSERT INTO summary(product_list_sid, amount, qty) VALUES (1,3,9), (1,15,45), (2,12,36);
```

I have written a query to join all the tables in such a way that I can get an exploded list of all products that are contained within the summarized table, along with the 'amount' and 'qty' values from the summary. Doing good so far...

query:

```
SELECT row_sid, product_description, amount, qty
FROM summary
INNER JOIN list_header ON summary.product_list_sid = list_header.product_list_sid
INNER JOIN list_detail ON list_header.product_list_sid = list_detail.product_list_sid
INNER JOIN product ON list_detail.product_sid = product.product_sid;
```

The result:

```
row_sid     product_description     amount  qty
1           can                     3       9
2           can                     15      45
1           can                     3       9
2           can                     15      45
1           bottle                  3       9
2           bottle                  15      45
3           can                     12      36
3           bottle                  12      36
3           bottle                  12      36
3           can                     12      36
```

I now would like to modify that query to also divide the 'amount' and 'qty' values by the number of rows that share the same row_sid.

So in this sample, every row with a row_sid of "1" or "2" would have 1/3 the 'amount' and 'qty' values and every row with row_sid of "3" would have 1/4 the 'amount' and 'qty' values.

This would theoretically result in the following table:

```
row_sid     product_description     amount  qty
1           can                     1       3
2           can                     5       15
1           can                     1       3
2           can                     5       15
1           bottle                  1       3
2           bottle                  5       15
3           can                     3       9
3           bottle                  3       9
3           bottle                  3       9
3           can                     3       9
```

I've gotten as far as this:

```
SELECT row_sid, product_description, amount / COUNT(row_sid) AS amount, qty / count(row_sid) AS qty
FROM summary
INNER JOIN list_header ON summary.product_list_sid = list_header.product_list_sid
INNER JOIN list_detail ON list_header.product_list_sid = list_detail.product_list_sid
INNER JOIN product ON list_detail.product_sid = product.product_sid
GROUP BY row_sid;
```

Which yields:

```
row_sid     product_description     amount  qty
1           can                     1       3
2           can                     5       15
3           can                     3       9
```

This gets the calculation right, but the GROUP BY is cutting out all of the other rows that I need. However, without the GROUP BY, I'm even further away from the goal.

What am I missing?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY all selected columns, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: I was unaware of that convention. I'm not too familiar with GROUP BY, but it seems I need it for my COUNT() to function properly. Adding the 'product_description' column to the GROUP BY still yields unwanted results.

Comment: Though, thinking about it, that definitely makes sense, since otherwise I'm simply throwing out things that I initially wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you need  a join between   query and a count for a  group rsult of the same query  ..

if you use only a query with group by you don't have all the rows because the group by  ... "group the data" so for avoid this beahvior of group by you could join the original query with the aggregated  one eg:

```
SELECT s.row_sid, product_description, amount/t.my_count, qty/t.my_count
FROM summary s
INNER JOIN list_header ON summary.product_list_sid = list_header.product_list_sid
INNER JOIN list_detail ON list_header.product_list_sid = list_detail.product_list_sid
INNER JOIN product ON list_detail.product_sid = product.product_sid
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT row_sid, COUNT(row_sid)  my_count
  FROM summary
  INNER JOIN list_header ON summary.product_list_sid = list_header.product_list_sid
  INNER JOIN list_detail ON list_header.product_list_sid = list_detail.product_list_sid
  INNER JOIN product ON list_detail.product_sid = product.product_sid
  GROUP BY row_sid;
) t on t.row_sid = s.row_sid
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Do you know if this approach would be considered horribly inefficient? I'm unsure of the order of magnitude of these various parts.

I'm more familiar with, say, nested loops in C#, which I would want to stay far away from on a large data set if at all possible.

Comment: for performance depend, obviously,  by number of rows involved but  if you have good indexes and a good server   and a reasonable cardinality could work  ..  reasonably fast ..  but are needed  more info for a specific evaluation related  to the performance. .. you can also think a partitioning  .. or some type of temp table ..